# How to share token across subdomains without including token in query parameter when redirected

Tags: angularjs, session, subdomain, session-cookies, token

I have login.company.com which authenticates user and generates token and then user would be redirected to subdomain. How do I pass the token in a secured way to subdomain apps (app1.company.com). We can redirect to subdomain with token in query parameter but I wanted to know if there is any alternate process. Would storing in local storage/ session storage/ cookie would help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I'd say the best way to do this is just to have SSL and to pass the token in as you currently are doing.

Without SSL, the token is at risk of being intercepted.

There is also the SAML authentication strategy
http://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/